# Развёртывание python кода на PythonAnyWhere

Tags: python, библиотеки, pythonanywhere

Есть простой код для Telegram бота:

```
import telebot

token = "XXX"
bot = telebot.TeleBot(token)

@bot.message_handler(content_types=["text"])
def handle_text(message):
if message.text == "Привет!":
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Привет) Как дела?")
else:
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Не понимаю!")

bot.polling(none_stop=True, interval=0)
```

Код использует библиотеку pyTelegramBotAPI. Пытаюсь запустить этот код на PythonAnyWhere.

При запуске файла консоль выдаёт ошибку: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'telebot'

Как загрузить модуль в консоль PythonAnyWhere? Есть ли другие способы развернуть код на python, использующий доп. библиотеки, на сервере?

Скрин ошибки при команде pip install:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Как обычно, через pip install

Comment: Как обычно не получается, прикрепил скрин ошибки к вопросу. 
Здесь сказано, что устанавливать новые модули можно только через Bash Console: http://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/InstallingNewModules

Comment: Запускаете bash console, в ней запускаете команд pip install. В консоли Python у вас естественно pip install не сработает.

Comment: А как потом запустить файл из bash console?

Comment: python3 main.py

Comment: А как остановить запуск файла?

Comment: Сочетанием клавиш Ctrl+c

Comment: Спасибо, это решило мою проблему!

Answer (score 2):

`pip install` нужно запускать в bash console, а не в консоли Python. Только для установки пакета в python3 нужно запускать `pip3 install имя_пакета`.

> А как потом запустить файл из bash console?

`python3 main.py`

> А как остановить запуск файла?

Сочетанием клавиш <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

Нужно прописать команду

```
pip install --user pytelegrambotapi
```

в Bash консоль